# Mathematica won't NIntegrate fairly simple equation, even tho Wolfram Alpha has no issue

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Here's my input:
`NIntegrate[sqrt[1 + (.00035 x^2)^2], {x, -625, 625}]`

The result is:

> NIntegrate::inumr: "The integrand sqrt[1+1.225*10^-7\ x^4] has
>   evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the
>   region with boundaries {{-625,0}}."

This links me to a page where I basically am told that I have to define x. Isn't that exactly what the range given as a second argument is doing? What am I not doing here?

[I can put the exact same syntax into WolframAlpha and get the right answer:](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bsqrt%5B1%20%2b%20%28.00035%20x%5E2%29%5E2%5D,%20%7Bx,%20-625,%20625%7D%5D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica is fussier than Wolfram Alpha about its input syntax.  Try

```
NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + (.00035 x^2)^2], {x, -625, 625}]
```

Comment: dang Sqrt is capitalized! grrrr.